# How can I use Tycho to download the content of a `.target` file to disk?

Tags: eclipse, tycho, p2

I have an eclipse `.target` file which I want to cache locally. I want to provide the users of my project with a means to execute a maven project to download the content into a P2 or archived P2 repository structure on the local disk.

Note: I am aware of the wrappers for the P2 director and other extra tools. This question is about using a target file as the input to that functionality.

Comment: If im not wrong, you want to export your eclipse target file containing artifacts to the local desk in P2 conform repository?